# How long did the meeting run vs How long did the meeting last?

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between the following sentences:

> 1 How long did the meeting run?

> 2 How long did the meeting last?

I found out that according to the collins dictionary run can also mean last

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/run

meaning number 32.

Comment: They're identical.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and will be understood.

I find *last* more common, and *run* more informal.

[image]